# laravel, how can I add extra attribute to model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `product` table and a `sub_product` table.

In `product` table there are many global field like `name` and `cat_id` .
In `sub_product` table there are `product_id`, `color` and `Price`

Now I want add a filed only to `product` laravel model(collection) that give me minimum `price` for each `product` from`sub_product`. how can I do that?

Comment: I think you have to declare a variable in product, say $minPrice and in controllorer you have to calculate value of this variable by checking price of each subproduct .

Comment: Also, if you have some code you tried, please share it with us.

Comment: @Diabolus no I dont want calculate in controller. only just like a filed in table that there is every where and every relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Product class, define relationship:

```
public function subproducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubProduct::class);
}
```

Define an accessor method:

```
public function getMinimumPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->subproducts()->min('price');
}
```

Retrieve value as field:

```
$price = $product->minimum_price;
```

Comment: protected $appends = array('min_price'); 

add this in model. when use ->toArray() can see this filed.

do you know how can I show this filed in collection view inside of attributes? 

thank you.

Comment: @HamidNaghipour, how do you want to use it with in collection? For example, what would the code look like?

Comment: @HamidNaghipour, depending on the collection method, you could use a closure, and access `$product->minimum_price` inside that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should define a relationship in product model  with sub_product model  and then you can query the product based on this relationship. THe relationship will be one to many.

```
 public function hasSubPRoducts(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\SubProduct','product_id','id');
    }
```

then query the model

```
 \App\Products::where('products_id',$id)-
>with(['hasSubPRoducts',function($query){
$query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
}
])->get()->first();
```

Comment: thank you. what about when I want get like this :  \App\category->with("Products") ?

Comment: then you would user nested relationship using Dot operator
\App\category->with("Products.hasSubPRoducts")

Comment: you mean like this?! 

\App\category::-
>with(['Products.hasSubPRoducts',function($query){
$query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
}
])->get()->first();

I think this is wrong!

Comment: \App\category::find($category_id)->with(['Products.hasSubPRoducts',function($query){ $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC'); } ])->get()->first();

Comment: \App\category::where('cat_id',2)->with(['Products.hasSubPRo‌​ducts',function($que‌​ry){ $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC'); } ])->get()->first();

where cat_id will be name of category id column in your table this will work like charm.